# Matlab openfig on headless display

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-figure

I'm running matlab on my local machine and I'm calling the following function from Java (running in a tomcat web server):

```
function df = getFig(file)
    f = openfig(file,'reuse','invisible');
    set(f, 'Color', [1,1,1]);
    df = webfigure(f);
    close(f);
end
```

This works fine locally but when running on our headless unix webserver we get this error:

```
{Error using set
Width and height must be > 0

Error in
renderwebfigure>@(childHnd,childPos)set(childHnd,'Position',[childPos(1)*parameters.width-clipRect(1)+extraRenderSpace,childPos(2)*parameters.height-clipRect(2)+extraRenderSpace,childPos(3)*parameters.width,childPos(4)*parameters.height])
(line 70)



Error in renderwebfigure>cropFigureAndReturnCData (line 70)



Error in renderwebfigure (line 31)


} 
Mar 30, 2012 4:08:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: WebFigures: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceDispatchTargetException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet.doGet(WebFiguresServlet.java:161)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceDispatchTargetException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.request.WebFigureRenderRequest.process(WebFigureRenderRequest.java:230)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.request.WebFigureRenderRequest.process(WebFigureRenderRequest.java:38)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureServiceFactory$WebFigureServiceImpl.processRequest(WebFigureServiceFactory.java:61)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureServiceFactory$WebFigureServiceImpl.processRequest(WebFigureServiceFactory.java:42)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet$1.call(WebFiguresServlet.java:147)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet$1.call(WebFiguresServlet.java:145)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet.doGet(WebFiguresServlet.java:158)
                ... 17 more
Caused by: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceDispatchTargetException: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.StatefulServicePeerCache.dispatch(StatefulServicePeerCache.java:174)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.request.WebFigureRenderRequest.process(WebFigureRenderRequest.java:221)
                ... 23 more
Caused by: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl.renderImage(WebFigureBinder.java:260)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl.renderEncoded(WebFigureBinder.java:329)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.request.WebFigureRenderRequest$1.execute(WebFigureRenderRequest.java:223)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.request.WebFigureRenderRequest$1.execute(WebFigureRenderRequest.java:221)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.services.StatefulServicePeerCache.dispatch(StatefulServicePeerCache.java:171)
                ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl$1.call(WebFigureBinder.java:254)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl$1.call(WebFigureBinder.java:252)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl.whileLocked(WebFigureBinder.java:191)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureBinder$WebFigurePeerImpl.renderImage(WebFigureBinder.java:252)
                ... 28 more
Caused by: com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Error using set
Width and height must be > 0
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:23)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:833)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:731)
                at $Proxy4.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:406)
                at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.service.WebFigureServiceMCR.renderwebfigure(WebFigureServiceMCR.java:211)
                ... 36 more
```

Other figures that I generate either my using plot(1:10); work fine on both platforms. So it seems the problem is with the openfig function. Also, if I path in a path to a file that doesn't exist I get a file not found error rather than the width and height must be > 0 error

Calling this however works:

```
function w = getplot
    f = figure('visible', 'off');
    plot(1:10);
    w = webfigure(f);
    close(f);
end
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `webfigure`, not `openfig`.

Comment: I have that same webfigure function in the plot code I mentioned and that works. I'll post the code in the main question

Comment: Anyway the error looks like comes from `webfigure`. What do you have on the figure from the fig-file? Have you tried to do `plot(1:10)`, save it to fig-file, then open with your code?

Comment: I've done that as a manual process. IE run plot(1:10) command in matlab to open up a fig, and then saved it. I've then tried to open this file using the above code and get the same result. I've tried this with about 10 different fig files, all work locally, none work on the webserver

Comment: Well, a good question for MATLAB support then.

Comment: Actually this week it's a second time I found that figure from a fig-file and newly generated figure are not the same. In my previous case I couldn't print a new figure with export_fig, but no problem if I save it to fig-file and open again. Something related to objects handles. Still researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out for some reason the default size for these on a headless display (at least on our linux distro) is 0. This causes an error before the webfigure can be manually resized. So ultimately the fix was:

set(f, 'pos', [0 0 100 100]);

Comment: Seems like a MATLAB bug to me.